# Prove that language that has unequal 0's and 1's is not regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Given the language L { w | w has unequal number of 0's and 1's } show that it's not regular.

I tried to use pumping lemma choosing the word of the form $0^p$ $1^{2p}$ ensuring that we'll have to pump zeroes. But i don't understand how can we ensure that we'll get equal number of 0's and 1's this way.
Maybe i need to choose other kind of word?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It seems to be much easier to use the Myhill-Nerode theorem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $0^p1^n$ with some larger $n$ instead.
What we want is that for all $k$ with $1\le k\le p$, there exists $m$ such that $0^{km}0^{p-k}1^n\notin L$.
So we want to find $n$ such that $km+p-k=n$ for suitable $m$. In other words, $n-p$ must be a multiple fo all $k\le p$. Try $n=p!+p$.

Comment: Note that here it is crucial that the pumping lemma guarantees that you can split a word into $xyz$ such that the pumping part $y$ is contained entirely within a bounded-length prefix of the original word. It seems to be not uncommon for presentations of the lemma to omit this part -- and the language in this question actually does satisfy the _thus weakened_ lemma.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.